# Unable to create new WebAPI solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Whenever I try to create a new solution in Visual Studio 2015, I receive the error

> The system cannot find the file specified (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700002)

The menu path is New Project>Web>ASP.NET Web Application>WebAPI with MVC and Web API check boxes selected below. The following error is received.

I've gone to Tools>Extensions and Updates to uninstall Nuget Package Manager and then re-installed, however I still get the same error. 
Environment is Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

[image]